# Give specific local Windows user group read access to a folder and its subfolders

Tags: c#, .net, windows, file-permissions

I want to programmatically give the local user group `<MachineName>\IIS_IUSRS` access to a folder and its subfolders.

My current code is looking like this:

```
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
DirectorySecurity directorySecurity = directoryInfo.GetAccessControl();

var groupName = Environment.MachineName + @"\IIS_IUSRS";

directorySecurity.AddAccessRule(
    new FileSystemAccessRule(groupName,
    FileSystemRights.Read,
    InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
    PropagationFlags.None,
    AccessControlType.Allow));

directoryInfo.SetAccessControl(directorySecurity);
```

But this is throwing a `System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException`. Replacing `groupName` with the SID for `new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);` is working.

Do I need to get a `SecurityIdenfier` for a group and if yes how do I do that? Or do I need to do it completely different for groups?

**Edit:** `BUILTIN\IIS_IUSRS` didn't work either as I'm using Windows with German locale.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# code to automatically give IIS write access to a folder on Windows Server 2008? Currently throws exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374784/c-sharp-code-to-automatically-give-iis-write-access-to-a-folder-on-windows-serve)

Comment: @AlexK. I found that question and it is in fact where I got the general code (`DirectorySecurity.....` etc.) but it doesn't work on my machine (Windows 10 version 1709). The exception is still telling me that the user could not be translated.

Comment: The linked code uses BUILTIN not MACHINENAME to identify that builtin group, does BUILTIN\IIS_IUSRS not work either?

Comment: @AlexK. Correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use the SID, I wrote a program for work once which used "DOMAIN\GroupName" and it worked fine. Instead of:

```
var groupName = Environment.MachineName + @"\IIS_IUSRS";
```

Try:

```
var groupName = @".\IIS_IUSRS";
```

Comment: This did it. The suggested `BUILTIN\IIS_IUSRS` from the other question did not work. `.\IIS_IUSRS` is the correct way with Windows 10 for me.

Comment: Thanks. It works also correctly on Windows Server 2016 for me.